# Field widget item form alter for file field

Tags: entities, files

I want to alter field widget item form of a file field with `cardinality > 1` so that a new form element is added to each row of the file tables. For example, in the attached image, I want to add another text field below the "Description" for each uploaded file, even the one done via Ajax, not just the existing ones. I used `hook_field_widget_form_alter()` but it doesn't seem to work with the newly uploaded file. Any ideas?

[image: File field table]

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the build logic for the file field widgets is handled in #process callbacks, so some detailed structures of each individual file's form element aren't really available during `hook_form_alter()`s.

You might want to preprocess the individual elements with `hook_preprocess_file_widget()`. Something like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_file_widget().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_file_widget(&$vars) {
  // Make some alterations to normal file-field widgets.
  $element = &$vars['element'];
  if (isset($element['#file']) && is_object($element['#file'])) {
    // This is an existing file... alter $element accordingly.
  }
  else {
    // This is the actual upload widget... you may want to skip this or alter
    // it in a special way.
  }
}
```

You could also use `hook_preprocess_file_widget_multiple()` to specifically target a group of files in a file field that has cardinality > 1. In this case you may need to have some iteration logic to loop through the children elements with `element_children()`.

Comment: For image fields, the hook is `MYMODULE_preprocess_image_widget(&$vars) {}`